# C#, xUnit class object reference conflict in other test classes

Tags: moq, xunit, .net-5, xunit.net, autofixture

I have .NET CORE 5 application with test written in xUnit along with fixture and moq. I have object that is part of expectation behaviour.

I have created instance of it and assign values accordingly. One of this class property is `CustomMessage`.

The issue is values assign in one test class of this object conflict with other test Classes. So If I run test individually by class then it passes and it fail if I run all the tests in one go. The issue is `queryResultSiteSummaryMoq` object.

QueryResultSummary Class

```cs
public class QueryResultSummary
{
    public int RecordsCount { get; set; }
    public bool IsRecordExist { get; set; }
    public bool Error { get; set; }
    public string ExecutionMessage { get; set; }
    public string CustomMessage { get; set; }
    public Exception Exceptions { get; set; }
}
```

Test Method

```cs
[Fact]
[Trait("Method", "GetSite")]
[Description("Site found, then return type must be of SiteWithStatusDataView In ResponseObject")]
public async Task ShouldReturn_SiteWithStatusDataView_Type_IfExist()
{
    //Arrange
    var fixture = new Fixture();

    int siteId = 3086;
    long lastUpdatedDateTimeUTC = 1628895600000;
    DateTime registeredLastUpdatedDateTimeInRecord = DateTime.Parse("10/08/2021 10:33:40");

    var lastUpdatedDateTime = DateTimeCalculationHelper.ConvertMillisecondToDateTime(lastUpdatedDateTimeUTC).DateTime;

    var lastUpdatedDateTimeWithMilliSecond = DateServices.RemoveMilliSecond(lastUpdatedDateTime);

    string SiteSearchStatus = $"Request, Processed With Provided LastDateTime: {lastUpdatedDateTimeWithMilliSecond} With Actual LastDateTime: {registeredLastUpdatedDateTimeInRecord}";

    fixture.Customize<SiteDataView>(c => c
        .With(x => x.SiteId, siteId)
        .With(x => x.IsActive, true)
        .With(x => x.IsDeleted, false)
        .With(x => x.UpdatedDateTimeUTC, registeredLastUpdatedDateTimeInRecord)
    );

    var siteMoq = fixture.Create<SiteDataView>();

    getSiteQueryMoq.Setup(x => x.SiteId).Returns(siteId);
    getSiteQueryMoq.Setup(x => x.Execute()).ReturnsAsync((1, siteMoq));

    var siteWithStatusDataViewMoq = new SiteWithStatusDataView
    {
        IsLastUpdateDateTimeProvided = true,
        IsSiteModified = RecordStatusEnum.Yes.ToString(),
        Site = siteMoq
    };

    //issue is following object
    var queryResultSiteSummaryMoq = new QueryResultSummary
    {
        RecordsCount = siteMoq == null ? 0 : 1,
        IsRecordExist = true,
        Error = false,
        ExecutionMessage = QueryExecutionStatusEnum.Success.ToString(),
        Exceptions = (Exception)null,
        CustomMessage = SiteSearchStatus
    };

    var expectedResult = (siteWithStatusDataViewMoq, queryResultSiteSummaryMoq);

    //Act
    var actualData = await sut.GetSite(siteId, lastUpdatedDateTimeUTC);
    var extractedActualResult = actualData;

    //Assert
    extractedActualResult.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expectedResult);
    Assert.IsAssignableFrom<SiteWithStatusDataView>(extractedActualResult.Item1);

    queryResultSiteSummaryMoq = null;
}
```

I have also tried fixture but still no luck

```cs
fixture.Customize<QueryResultSummary>(c => c
 .With(x => x.RecordsCount, exemptions == null ? 0 : exemptions.Count)
 .With(x => x.IsRecordExist, true)
 .With(x => x.Error, false)
 .With(x => x.ExecutionMessage, QueryExecutionStatusEnum.Success.ToString())
 .With(x => x.Exceptions, (Exception)null)
 .With(x => x.CustomMessage, string.Empty)
);
```

Comment: *So If I run test individually by class then it passes and it fail if I run all the tests in one go.* >> This might indicate that you have a shared component between test cases which is not reseted properly between the cases. What do you share?

Comment: You have issue with multiple tests, can you show the whole test class?

Comment: @PeterCsala I have class QueryResultSummary which is used for all the classes but I am create new instance when creating for specific test case. i.e. var queryResultSummary = new QueryResultSummary{... //set properties values here to satisfy each class }

Comment: Then could you please elaborate on this *The issue is queryResultSiteSummaryMoq object.*?

Answer (score 1):

The most likely reason for two test classes to interfere with each other is for them to share some sort of state, which is a common bad practice and a violation of the [F.I.R.S.T](https://hackernoon.com/test-f-i-r-s-t-65e42f3adc17) principles.

Since the `sut` instance, and a few other objects are not declared in the test, so I assume you have some sort of setup phase in which you declare them. Make sure none of the shared instances survive in between test runs and also that no resources (object instances) are shared in between test classes.

Since you use AutoFixture consider delegating the setup to the Fixture instance. This will make it easier to isolate your tests from one another, making them thread safe, and also your tests will be less verbose and easier to maintain.